# Google Place Autocomplete Component Restriction - Miami-Dade County, Florida, United States

Tags: jquery, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am searching for this solution.
I am using google place autocomplete and types geocode.

i can restrict only in **country** by using **country code {country:'us'}**.
but using others component restriction property its not working for specific **county**: **Miami-Dade County in Florida,** USA.

When i apply any other component restriction its not return any search result on 
place autocomplete text area.

Answer (score 0):

The components `country` only accepts a value of [ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) compatible country code. And it's only composed of 2 letters. Now, to use multiple components in a single request, you need to use the pipe character (|) as a separator. For example: **components=country:us|country:pr|country:vi** would restrict your results to places within the United States and its unincorporated organized territories. For more information, check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_requests).

Comment: actually  I want to restricted search on Miami-Dade County in Florida state in USA. Not multiple countries, Only in USA.

Comment: Then you can use the [Location Biasing](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#location_biasing), You may bias results to a specified circle by passing a location and a radius parameter. This instructs the Place Autocomplete service to prefer showing results within that circle. Results outside of the defined area may still be displayed. You can use the components parameter to filter results to show only those places within a specified country.

Comment: Or [Location Restrict](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#location_restrict), to restrict results to the region defined by location and a radius parameter, by adding the strictbounds parameter. This instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only results within that region.

Comment: can you please give a jsfiddle example of it, if possible. because I have tried, but can't understand where should be put everything.